QFT schwartz chapter 3b. total derivative
I am trying to improve my knowledge of QFT and was going through Schwartz's QFT. In question. 3.2 you are asked to evaluate how $$Q=\int \mathcal{T}_{00} d^3 x$$ changes when you add a total derivative $\partial_{\mu}X$ to the Lagrangian.
I have gotten that the stress energy tensor changes
$$\Delta T_{\mu v}=\frac{\partial\left(\partial_\lambda X\right)}{\partial\left(\partial_\nu \phi\right)} \partial_{\nu} \phi-g_{\mu v} \partial_\lambda X$$
but am struggling with showing that this is conserved. In solutions I have found online the procedure seems to be switching the derivative via integration by parts but I don't really understand why the total derivative should dissapear in this case. Basically it seems like you should have something like this.
\begin{aligned}
& \Delta Q=\int \left(\frac{\partial\left(\partial_\lambda X\right)}{\partial(\dot{\phi})} \dot{\phi}-\partial_\lambda X\right)d^3 x \\
& \Delta Q=\int\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{\phi}}\left(\partial_\lambda X \dot{\phi}\right)-2 \partial_\lambda X\right) d^3 x
\end{aligned}
Where in the solutions I have found online the first term somehow dissapears, but it is not a total derivative with respect to the coordinates but rather the field so I don't understand why it should.

X vanishes on the boundary at infinity, no?

Doesn't this only apply to the second term where we have the total derivative of X? I think I just struggle to see what happens with regards to any dependence of phi dot on X.
